# Grouping images by time interval python

Tags: python, image, time

I have a script with taking out exif data from images, and putting it into to the list, I sort my list after and that's what i have its a list of lists, on first position its a image time in seconds and 2nd place its a image path, its my list,

> [[32372, 'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013025.JPG'], [32373, 'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013026.JPG'], [32373, 'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013027.JPG'],.... etc etc etc

That a script with grouping my images made by @blhsing , with works great, but I want to start my grouping , not from first image , start grouping by given position
That a script:

```
groups = []
for r in img:
    if groups and r[0] - groups[-1][-1][0] <= 5:
        groups[-1].append(r)
    else:
        groups.append([r])
for g in groups:
    print(g[0][1], g[0][0], g[-1][0], g[-1][1])
```

And that what I have and , its does not work well , its taking only one image, , does no create a group , did somebody can help me please to fix it ??

```
groups = []
print(iii, "iii")
#print(min_list, " my min list ")
img.sort()
cnt = 0
mili = [32372, 34880]

for n in min_list:
    #print(n, "mili")
    for i in img:
        #print(i[0])
        if n == i[0]:
            if groups and i[0] - groups[-1][-1][0] <= 5:
                groups[-1].append(i)
            else:
                groups.append([i])
    for ii in groups:
        print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
```

Over here I have my min_list with 2 position means I want to create only 2 groups , and classifier only images starting from those 2 position , with interval as before 5 seconds.

Comment: Please, provide your desired output to see clearly what do you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `img` list is sorted by time already, you can iterate through the records and append them to the last sub-list of the output list (named `groups` in my example code) if the time difference to the last entry is no more than 5 seconds; otherwise put the record into a new sub-list of the output list. Keep in mind that in Python a subscript of `-1` means the last item in a list.

```
groups = []
for r in img:
    if groups and r[0] - groups[-1][-1][0] <= 5:
        groups[-1].append(r)
    else:
        groups.append([r])
for g in groups:
    print(g[0][1], g[0][0], g[-1][0], g[-1][1])
```

Comment: Can You explain me whats thats mine all [0], [-1], groups[-1][-1][0],g[0][1] etc please, working great thank You a lot :-), and @AKX thank You too :-)

Comment: And we can take only image name from the path ??

Comment: You can use [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to obtain the image name from the path. I'll add comments to my answer to explain the logic in a moment.

Comment: Thank You for explication @blhsing

Comment: how we can modify it to get only 1st group starting from 1st image(image the base)  in my list and take only those images, with interval is smallest than 5 seconds , and stops when interval to next images in my list is biggest than 5 seconds (means do not create next groups)?

Comment: If you mean the first group, that would be `groups[0]` wouldn't it?

Comment: I figured it out after long morning :-) Thank You for Your help once again :-)

Comment: Just if can told me why 1st if and -groups[-1][-1][0] << there is tree position ?

Comment: No problem. :-) The goal here is to group the images into a list of sub-lists, with each sub-list having images that were taken within 5 seconds of each others. Each image itself is a 2-item list, with the first item being the time the image was taken, and the second item being the path to the image file. Therefore, the output variable, `groups`, is a list of lists of lists, and `groups[-1][-1][0]` means to get the time of the latest image of the latest image group, in order to compare to the time of the image in the current iteration, which is stored in `r[0]`.

Comment: Thank You , I still have some problem, when I using Your code works super well, but when I want to start from my second list and putting it to i[0] its getting only beginning time and don't want create whole group, have You any idee why ??

Comment: I still can't create my groups from chosen position, how we can do it

Comment: mili = [32372, 34880]

for n in mili:
    print(n, "mili")
    for i in img:
        #print(i[0])
        if n == i[0]:
            if groups and i[0] - groups[-1][-1][0] <= 5:
                groups[-1].append(i)
            else:
                groups.append([i])
    for ii in groups:
        print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it , like over here I want to start my 1st group from 32372 and second from 34880 and create only those 2 groups, can You help please, :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sure! I just actually wrote this same algorithm the other day, but for JavaScript. Easy to port to Python...

```
import pprint

def group_seq(data, predicate):
    groups = []
    current_group = None
    for datum in data:
        if current_group:
            if not predicate(current_group[-1], datum):  # Abandon the group
                current_group = None
        if not current_group:  # Need to start a new group
            current_group = []
            groups.append(current_group)
        current_group.append(datum)
    return groups


data = [
    [32372, r'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013025.JPG'],
    [32373, r'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013026.JPG'],
    [32373, r'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013027.JPG'],
    [32380, r'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0064646.JPG'],
    [32381, r'F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0064646.JPG'],
]

groups = group_seq(
    data=data,
    predicate=lambda a, b: abs(a[0] - b[0]) > 5,
)

pprint.pprint(groups)
```

outputs

```
[[[32372, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013025.JPG'],
  [32373, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013026.JPG'],
  [32373, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013027.JPG']],
 [[32380, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0064646.JPG'],
  [32381, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0064646.JPG']]]
```

Basically the `predicate` is a function that should return `True` if `b` belongs in the same group as `a`; for your use case, we look at the (absolute) difference of the first items in the tuples/lists, which is the timestamp.